# How make InputType flexible in GraphQL in node.js?

Tags: node.js, graphql

My question is clear and simple about implementing GraphQL with Node.js.

There's two mutations. One is `createUser` and another is `updateUser`. Both mutations have argument `user` which is `UserInputType`.

```
const UserInputType = new GraphQLInputObjectType({
  name: 'UserInputType',
  description: 'a user input type',
  fields: () => {
    return {
      username: {
        type: GraphQLString,
        description: 'a unique username for a user',
      },
      email: {
        type: GraphQLString,
        description: 'a unique email for a user',
      },
      password: {
        type: GraphQLString,
        description: 'a strong password for a user',
      },
    };
  },
});
```

The problem is, `createUser` mutation needs **all parameters** username, email and password.
`updateUser` needs just at least one parameter. Do I have to implement two `UserInputType`s for each mutation? I think that's not good way.

Hope a clue!

Comment: I think the correct way to do it would be to create two input types. I don't think it is possible to do what you want, and even if it was, I would advise against it. A dynamic schema is IMO undesirable.

Comment: @sboutzen you are right, it should be static schema. I was foolish!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to omit fields of the input type when invoking a mutation. The code handling that mutation will have `undefined` value for the missing fields.

If the set of data needed for `createUser` and `updateUser` are the same, then a single input type will do. In that case, whether the client provided all parameters has to be checked for `createUser`, which can be done in `mutateAndGetPayload` function in the following example code. Another way is to have the client check for this (if you write the client). This approach has the advantage of avoiding duplicate code for the same fields.

Another way is to define two separate, yet mostly duplicate, types. The only difference is input object type for `updateUser` has `GraphQLString`, whereas the other object type for `createUser` has `GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)`. This approach has the advantage of avoiding check for null parameters. However, I think, it is sane to check input validity at some point. Null value is just one of the many invalid values.

Following the first approach, I extended your `UserInputType` with a field `id` (usually used in update operation to identify the user) and implemented both `createUserMutation` and `updateUserMutation`.

In the code, `mutationWithClientMutationId` is a helper function from [graphql-relay](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-relay-js) library.

```
const UserInputType = new GraphQLInputObjectType({
  name: 'UserInputType',
  description: 'a user input type',
  fields: {
      id: { type: GraphQLID },
      .....
      .....
  },
});

const createUserMutation = mutationWithClientMutationId({
  name: 'CreateUser',
  inputFields: {
    user: { type: UserInputType },
  },
  outputFields: {
    id: {
      type: GraphQLID,
      resolve: ({id}) => id,
    },
  },
  mutateAndGetPayload: ({user}) => {
    console.log('@ createUserMutation: Received user input:');
    console.log(`id: ${user.id}, username: ${user.username}, email: ${user.email}, password: ${user.password}`);
    if (hasValidInputs(user.username, user.email, user.password)) {
        return {id: '9999999'};
    } else {
        return {id: '-1'}
    }
  },
});

const updateUserMutation = mutationWithClientMutationId({
  name: 'UpdateUser',
  inputFields: {
    user: { type: UserInputType },
  },
  outputFields: {
    status: {
      type: GraphQLBoolean,
      resolve: ({status}) => status,
    },
  },
  mutateAndGetPayload: ({user}) => {
    console.log('@ updateUserMutation: Received user input:');
    console.log(`id: ${user.id}, username: ${user.username}, email: ${user.email}, password: ${user.password}`);
    return {status: true};
  },
});
```

Running the GraphQL server using [express-graphql](https://github.com/graphql/express-graphql), `updateMutation` can be tested with the following:

```
mutation {
  updateUser(input: {
    clientMutationId:"12344", 
    user: {
      username: "new username"
    }
  }) {
    clientMutationId,
    status,
  }
}
```

GraphQL server responds with:

```
{
  "data": {
    "updateUser": {
      "clientMutationId": "12344",
      "status": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In your code, what's `mutationWithClientMutationId`? Is your personal function? I need more explanation.

Comment: It's a helper function from graphql-relay library (a npm package). Which other parts do you think need should be elaborated more?

Comment: What I meant was all of `createUser` input arguments should be **NonNull** parameter. Then client can't omit a parameter if same input object. This code even doesn't. As the first commenter's advice, dividing two InputObjectType is right.

Comment: In your question, you wanted to use the same input object type for both mutations which, I think, is a better approach. I edited my answer explaining both approaches with pros and cons of each. Hope it helps.